# How can i suppress Info and Warnings in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I run a powershell command :

```
   az storage blob delete --account-name   etc etc
```

It runs successfully but gives Info LIKE THE FOLLOWING:

```
      az : INFO: Try to get storage auth_mode value from environment variables or 
      config file.At line:11 char:1
```

How can i suppress this in the output ?